# How to assign class weights for a Logistic Regression Model in Apache Spark's MLlib (Python)

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am working on a binary classification problem with an imbalanced dataset where 75% of the data belongs to the negative class(`0.0`) and the rest (25%) belongs to the positive class(`1.0`).

I am using a PySpark Dataframe where each row has a label (0.0 or 1.0) associated with it for indicating the class. Due to the imbalance of the classes, I would like to use appropriate class weights.

From the documentation and the example listed [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.html#pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression), there's a parameter called `weightCol` in the line
`blor = LogisticRegression(weightCol="weight")`

The description of `weightCol` is mentioned [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.html#pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.weightCol).

So can I go ahead and create a new column called `weight`, assign a value of `0.75` whenever the label is `1.0` and `0.25` when the label is `0.0` for every row and initialise the model as mentioned above?

I just want to check if this is the right way to assign weights to an imbalanced dataset in Spark MLlib as the documentation doesn't make it really clear

Answer (score 2):

Yes that can be one method. We are calculating the weights based on the ratio of samples of each of the classes in the entire population. Also, the weights sum up to 1.

However, if you check the formula from the official sklearn documentation as mentioned here [sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html#) they use a slightly different formula. The weights are calculated for each of the classes by `n_samples / (n_classes * np.bincount(y))` If you are looking for something like that the following snippet might be helpful:

```py
y_collect = df.select('label').groupBy('label').count().collect()
bin_counts = {y['label']: y['count'] for y in y_collect}
total = sum(bin_counts.values())
n_labels = len(bin_counts)
weights = {bin_: total/(n_labels*count) for bin_, count in bin_counts.items()}
df = df.withColumn('weight', F.when(F.col('label')==1.0, weights[1]).otherwise(weights[0])).show()
```

Comment: Great answer, +1. Any insight as to whether one approach is better than the other?